# Webpack build warning

Tags: reactjs, webpack

here is my problem i build a react app by using webpack, but it gives this warning

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `id` is required to make `n` accessible for users of assistive technologies such as screen readers.

so how to solve it?

webpack code:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/index.html'})
  ],
  entry:{
    index: './src/index.js'
  },
  output:{
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: "static/react_veg/dist/",
    filename: 'boundle.js'
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
      {test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader','css-loader'] },
      {test: /\.(js|jsx)$/ ,use:'babel-loader'},
      {test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, use:'url-loader?limit=8192'}
    ]
  },
  resolve:{
    alias:{},
    extensions:[".js"]
  }
}
```

Comment: In a third party component you are missing the `id` prop. It should mention which component that is in the error log.

Comment: Please, show us some code...

Comment: sorry i never meet this problem before, so i dont know where the problem is,when i using npm start,it has no problem,but when using webpack appears so ...

Comment: i use create-react-app